# Suppress records from one table that are also in another table

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

List1 is my main table and List2 is a secondary table. Is there a way to display people from List1 that are *not* on List2? Or suppress if they *are* on List2?

The common field is `personID`.

```
List1:  
name;id           
Ed Newb;1  
John Law;2  
Mike Jordan;3  

List2:  
name;id   
Ed Newb; 1  
Mike Jordan; 3
Other Guy; 4
```

I am seeking a query that will remove data on list2 from list1:

```
Report:  
List1.name;List1.id   
John Law; 2
```

Comment: remove from database or crystal reports?

Comment: Remove from the report @siva

Comment: What is your report structure

Comment: List1: PersonName; PersonId.   List2:PersonName; PersonId.

Comment: Try filtering it out in SQL instead of in your report. Write a query that only pulls records into your report if they are from Table1 and *not* in Table2. It would be a *lot* more work than it's worth to try and make your report figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can filter them out in SQL:

```
SELECT
  l1.id,
  l1.name
FROM 
  list1 l1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN list2 l2 ON l1.id = l2.id
WHERE
  l2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I'll give this a shot

Comment: This worked @Carlos Torres, what if I also wanted to ignore some records in list 2, effectively keeping them in my query, ex.   l2.id <> '1'

Comment: You can add an AND clause to the LEFT JOIN